# Why is my MKCoordinateRegion nil?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So I've got the following function to set my map region for my app:

```
func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion {

    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").child(runName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let runData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        self.minLat = runData?["startLat"] as? Double
        self.minLng = runData?["startLong"] as? Double
        self.maxLat = runData?["endLat"] as? Double
        self.maxLng = runData?["endLong"] as? Double
        print("testing")
        print(self.minLat!)
        print(self.maxLng!)

        self.coordinate = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.minLat! + self.maxLat!)/2,
                                           longitude: (self.minLng! + self.maxLng!)/2),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (self.maxLat! - self.minLat!)*1.1,
                                   longitudeDelta: (self.maxLng! - self.minLng!)*1.1))

    })

    return coordinate

}
```

I have initialised the following variables at the top of my class:

```
var minLat: Double!
var minLng: Double!
var maxLat: Double!
var maxLng: Double!
var coordinate: MKCoordinateRegion!
```

And am trying to set the map region as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()
    mapView.region = mapRegion()
}
```

The error I am getting is in the lines where I am setting my coordinate region under the block of code that contains my databaseHandle in mapRegion(). When the code is running, I get the following error under the line 'return coordinate':

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

To my understanding, this is occurring because 'coordinate' has no values and is an Optional. Why is it that coordinate has no values even though I am setting it up using a global variable? I feel like I am missing something so simple!

Thanks

Comment: *I have initialised the following variables at the top of my class*. No you haven't. You have **declared** the variables as implicit unwrapped optionals. They don't have an initial value, therefore they are `nil` and can cause a crash.

Comment: The problem is `return coordinate` will call before you initialized it it happens because completion block of `observe` will call async when you get response so what you need is to create completion block with your `mapRegion` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because `observe` works asynchronously and it is impossible to return a value from a method containing a asynchronous task.

You need a completion handler

```
func mapRegion(completion: (MKCoordinateRegion)->()) {

    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").child(runName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let runData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        self.minLat = runData?["startLat"] as? Double
        self.minLng = runData?["startLong"] as? Double
        self.maxLat = runData?["endLat"] as? Double
        self.maxLng = runData?["endLong"] as? Double
        print("testing")
        print(self.minLat!)
        print(self.maxLng!)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.minLat! + self.maxLat!)/2,
                                           longitude: (self.minLng! + self.maxLng!)/2),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (self.maxLat! - self.minLat!)*1.1,
                                   longitudeDelta: (self.maxLng! - self.minLng!)*1.1))
        completion(region)

    })
}
```

And use it

```
mapRegion() { region in
     mapView.region = region
     // do other things with the region
}
```

Side note:

There are too many question marks in the code. Use optional bindings to unwrap optionals safely.

Comment: ill give it a shot

Comment: Tried it no luck, same error....

I've tried moving out the observe function into a different method and had just the MKCoordinateRegion being returned in mapRegion(), and still same issue. I might try to set the map region differently.

Comment: If you are using the method exactly as described in the answer, the code must work. Of course you have to put all code relying on the received  region into the completion handler of `mapRegion()`. Please learn to understand asynchronous networking.

Comment: I've implemented it properly now and it's working, thanks. I'll definitely look into asynchronous networking in more detail.